# Closing Searchview by code (Android : androidx.appcompat.widget)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a Searchview in my action bar, for which I would like to have a special behaviour, but I can't achieve.
When clicking on search an edit field appears in the action bar.
When typing into the search edit field a list of results will be displayed on the fly, when typing.

So far so good, which is the default behaviour.

No I would like to close the searchfield when selecting any result from the list, but currently the searchfield keeps displaying in the action bar.

How can I close the searchfield by code ? (Same behaviour with clicking on the close icon)

Illustration:
Actionbar by default:

[image]

I click on search and start typing:

[image]

I choose first search result "Battle of Uruk":

[image]

The appbar still shows the field edit. I have to close the field by clicking on the close button. How can I hide the field by code, so the appbar looks like default first screenshot ?

```
searchView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  
                <close field and show search icon again>
                // my tries, which didn't work correctly
                //searchView.clearFocus();
                //searchView.setIconified(true);
                //searchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //searchItem.setVisible(true);

            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documantation says  : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView#setIconifiedByDefault(boolean)

```
 searchView.setQuery("", false);

 if (!searchView.isIconifiedByDefault()) {   
     searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
 }
```

Edit: setIconified(true) and isIconfied() are deprecated

Also try at menu to set app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried this in the onItemClick method, but nothing happens. searchfield is still visible.

Comment: Also figured out to clear text first with searchView.setQuery("", false);. Thanks a lot.